# Converting String to Integer have made my app to force close

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the system time, when I put it in a textView as string everything is ok, but when I convert string to Integer,it made my app to force close!
this is my code :

```
    TextView texttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttime);

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03:30");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+
    String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    Integer itime = Integer.valueOf(time);
    int mtime = (itime-2350);
    texttime.setText(mtime);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You are making really strange conversions here - that simply make no sense.

I am pretty sure that `setText()` expects a **String**. But you want to pass a primitive **int** to it.

You see - you already used that a String formatter to turn a Calender thingy into a string. So why do you **then** want to turn that into an Integer that you then turn into an int?!

Long story short: you should step back and clarify what kind of value you want to generate and where that should go to!

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to cast to Integer is not valid because this string concat make no sense

```
String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+
    String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Lets your time is 2:45 the value of the variable time would be something like: 2.0045.00", so the text you are trying to cast is not a valid value

Answer (score 0):

First of all `TextView` `setText` method except `String` as method parameter, but here you are passing an integer value.
`textView.setText(mtime)`

But even after you want to do this, then it can be achieved by adding a String literal to the integer.
`textView.setText(""+mtime)`